# Rotation of letter which aligns with the text line?

Tags: rotating

I want a symbol as "e", but rotated 180° around its center, so that the new symbol r(e) aligns with the other letters in the text: abgkr(e)etc.

How may this be achieved?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
e
\begin{rotate}{180}
    e
\end{rotate}e


\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{e}`.

Comment: @Celdor Thanks. How may I define it as a robust command? The text around seems to be affected, but that may be an optical illusion.

Comment: @Sapiens: `\NewDocumentCommand{\rote}{}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{e}}` and then use `e\rote e` (or potentially more flexibly: `\NewDocumentCommand{\rote}{O{180}}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{#1}{e}}`, which allows you to use `\rote`, `\rote[90]`, `\rote[-15]`, ...).

Comment: @Sapiens Sorry I couldn't respond earlier but I can see you have got a number of good answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An improvement to Sebastiano's fine answer.

The rotated “e” should, in my opinion be sligthly nudged up and a small kern added to the right.

If you look the “be” example, you see that the space between the two letters is larger than between the simply rotated “e” and the “e”.

The other problem is that “e” overshoots the x-height and we need to move it up a bit to compensate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{xcolor}% for the leading rules

\DeclareRobustCommand{\schwa}{%
  \mbox{%
    % nudge up
    \raisebox{0.015ex}{%
      % rotate
      \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{e}%
    }%
    % nudge left
    \kern0.02em
  }%
}

\newcommand{\showrules}{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\color{red}\vrule width 0.5cm height 0pt depth 0.1pt}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\color{red}\vrule width 0.5cm height \dimexpr1ex+0.1pt depth -1ex}%
}

\begin{document}

\showrules
e\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{e}e
\showrules
e\schwa e
\showrules
be

\end{document}
```

[image]

Different shifts might be needed with other fonts. Here the same parameters are used with `ebgaramond`.

[image]

Here we see that “e” overshoots both the x-height and the baseline; moreover the kerning doesn't seem necessary. With

```
\raisebox{-0.01ex}{...}
```

and no final kern we get

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! I will study your answer better tomorrow, but do you have an opinion as to whether a similarly rotated "u" should be somewhat altered, as in "slightly nudged up and a small kern added to the right"? (These special signs are to keep track of variables gotten by existential or universal instantiations)

Comment: @Sapiens I'm afraid that a rotated “u” is too similar to “n” to be effective. Look at [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWCfD.png) from a distance.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @egreg Indeed, thanks! To evade the problem, I decided to rotate "u" just forty degrees.

Answer (score 6):

With the suggestion of the user @Celdor,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
e\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{e}e
\end{document}
```

[image]